# How can I use a switch to hide one grid and show the other?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this code so far:

```
<ViewCell>
   <Grid>
      <Label Text="Custom Scores" />
      <Switch IsToggled="{Binding ShowPointsSwitch}" />
   </Grid>
</ViewCell>
<ViewCell Tapped="openPicker">
   <Grid IsVisible="{Binding ShowPointsSwitch}">
      <Label Text="ABC" />
   </Grid>
   <Grid IsVisible="{Binding ShowPointsSwitch, Converter={StaticResource InverseBoolConverter} }">
      <Label Text="DEF" />
   </Grid>
</ViewCell>
```

What I am trying to do is to have the switch hide and show the different grids but it's not working. All that happens is that it shows one label and then when the switch is moved it shows nothing.

Can someone give me advice on how I can fix this.  For reference.  Here's the ViewModel that I have:

```
    bool showPointsSwitch;

    public bool ShowPointsSwitch
    {
        get
        {
            return showPointsSwitch;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != showPointsSwitch)
            {
                showPointsSwitch = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ShowPointsSwitch");
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's the converter:

```
public class InverseBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return !(bool)value;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return !(bool)value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's basically because `ViewCell` is supposed to have only one child. 
Try using:

```
<ViewCell Tapped="openPicker">
  <Grid>
    <Label Text="ABC" IsVisible="{Binding ShowPointsSwitch}" />  
    <Label Text="DEF" IsVisible="{Binding ShowPointsSwitch, Converter={StaticResource InverseBoolConverter} }" />
  </Grid>
</ViewCell>
```

Or,

```
<ViewCell Tapped="openPicker">
  <Grid>
    <Grid IsVisible="{Binding ShowPointsSwitch}">
      <Label Text="ABC" />
    </Grid>
    <Grid IsVisible="{Binding ShowPointsSwitch, Converter={StaticResource InverseBoolConverter}}">
      <Label Text="DEF" />
    </Grid>
  </Grid>    
</ViewCell>
```

Comment: Can you explain what Source={x:Reference _parent} is doing here.  I'm not familiar with that. Also would the !ShowPointsSwitch work as suggested by Alessandro?

Comment: Sorry about that - that was a copy-paste mistake. I will update the answer. And, as far as I am aware - `!ShowPointsSwitch` shouldn't work. Maybe it is worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of you Converter, you can try with

```
{Binding !ShowPointsSwitch}
```